# removing proxy to avoid problems during installation

Tags: apt, java, proxy

i tried to install java and got this error

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main icedtea-6-jre-jamvm i386 6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1
Something wicked happened resolving 'proxy.ssn.net:8080' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

I think the proxy is causing trouble. `proxy.ssn.net:8080` is my college proxy.
How to remove this? Or is there anything else that is causing problem?

Comment: Can you ping the proxy? `ping proxy.ssn.net` Looks like a dns problem.

Comment: sorry!i don't how to ping proxy.how to do it?

Comment: @user305774: chaos posted the command to run.

Comment: @chaos Some campus proxy servers don't respond to ping (mine doesn't). Better try `nslookup` since the error is about resolving the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and type the following command:-

```
grep -Hnri proxy /etc/apt/
```

This will list out the current proxy settings used by apt in the following format- `filename:linenumber:proxy-setting`

If you see any output, it corresponds to apt's proxy settings. They will have to be cleared.

```
sudoedit <filename>
```

will allow you to edit the corresponding configuration file. Copy the existing contents somewhere in case you need to restore them, and delete or comment the lines that look like

```
Acquire::<protocol>::proxy=<your proxy here>
```

(Add `//` at the beginning of a line to comment that line. Commented lines are ignored.)

Save the files, close the text editor, and retry.